# css: Responsive Web Design

Tags: css, materialize, responsive-images

I am using Materialize CSS and AngularJS for making a product catalog page. I am having some trouble with landscape images. Screenshots and code are given below.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m10 l10">
        <div ng-repeat="info in products">
            <div class="col s6 m3 l3" id="no-padding">
                <div class="card" id="no-margin">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <div id="image-container">
                            <img id="image" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}" ng-style="{'height': '200px'}" class="responsive-img">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#image-container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#image {
    margin: auto;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #no-margin {margin: 0 !important;}
    #no-padding {padding: 0 !important;}
}
```

[image]

Dimension of product image on the right: 832 x 477 (landscape). Dimension of product image on the left: 552 x 832 (portrait). Product image on the right seems vertically stretched. Please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it. Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the image a set inline height, so it won't be able to scale properly, since it's always keeping the same height (just the width is changing).

Try out using a height of auto. That, along with setting a width of 100% would make it scale with the width of the container and the height would change accordingly.

```
.responsive-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

That should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set your img width to 100% & its height to auto.

Also set vertical alignment to middle to keep the image centred.

Side note: Angular JS is a really bad move for an eCommerce store. I would seriously reconsider it. It's bad enough that your blasting a css framework in there destroying text to code ratio but you can forget indexing with angular.

Comment: Please further explain your side note.

Comment: It's late my end about to head to bed but if you google angular js and seo youll get the idea. Angular is really meant for dynamic app's not static content sites like an eCommerce site